# Custom error message for invalide coupon code magento2

Tags: magento2, coupon, promotions, coupon-codes

I want to be able to set a specific error message for when the criteria of a promo code is not met.

For eg. I have promotion rule for t-shirt qty 1.

- Entered valid promo code
    No tshirts in shopping cart -> receive custom error message ("Limit 1 shirt per coupon code.")
- Greater than 1 tshirt in shopping cart - > receive custom error message ("Limit 1 shirt per coupon code.")
- 1 tshirt in the cart -> no error message; transaction is able to continue. (e.g. with free tshirt and free shipping)
- Entered invalid promo code -> receive default error message for invalid promo code

I need help to create this functionality.

I want to create this functionality in Magento2.

Answer (score 0):

Please follow below url to how to create promo code, so you better understand how to create promo code :

https://magenticians.com/how-to-create-coupon-code-magento-2/